# Criar PROCEDURE entrando dado e verificando em 2 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql

Pessoal estou com uma duvida em como fazer um PROCEDURE, elaborei uma imagem de guide para explicar minha duvida.

Legenda: Tabela em amarelo e coluna em azul, linkadas pela linha.

[image: Imagem Guide]

O imovel CASA1 tem o ID 23 esse imovel tem opçoes adicionais(features) como piscina, churrasqueira e por ai vai.

Como é uma base com mais de 25mil registros de imoveis, criamos uma tabela para listar as features com uma ID, Codigo e Descrição, no caso do desenho ilustrado como TABELA FEATURE.

Criamos tambem uma tabela TABELA FEATURE LINK que contem as IDs das features e as IDs dos imoveis, nela as IDs dos imoveis pode se repetir porque pode ter mais de uma feature, mais não repete as features por imovel.

Preciso fazer um PROCEDURE que tenha a entrada do ID do imovel e retorne organizado as features JUNTAS de cada imovel com sua ID.

Se puderem ajudar agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer algo parecido com isto:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.* from tabela_imovel a 
  inner join tabela_feature b on a.id=b.id 
  inner join tabela_feature_link c on a.id=c.id 
where EXCLUSÕES
```